# Why does @output event produce error "TypeError: _co.XXXXX is not a function'

Tags: angular-components

Writing an Angular child component, and can't convince the parent to capture a value emitted through @Output.  It throws an error that the receiver _co.pinEvent is undefined.  During initialization, though, the debugger shows it successfully making the call.  So it's not a simple typo.

Followed every guide and question I could find, cut it down to minimal example, and still can't get it to work.  The component reference _co seems to be pointing at something other than the home component.

### home.module.ts

```
...
import { KeypadComponent } from '../keypad/keypad.component';

@NgModule({
...
  declarations: [HomePage, KeypadComponent]
})
export class HomePageModule {
    digits: number;
    title: string;
    change: any;

    constructor() {
    }

    pinEvent($event) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify($event));
    }

}
```

### home.page.html

```
<ion-content>
    <ble-lock-keypad (pinValue)="pinEvent($event)"></ble-lock-keypad>

  Once the component is visible, any event emitted
  from child causes this pinEvent() call to fail on
  an undefined reference.
</ion-content>
```

### keypad.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'ble-lock-keypad',
  templateUrl: './keypad.component.html'
})
export class KeypadComponent {
    @Output() pinValue: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

    constructor() {
     }

    handleInput(key: string) {
        this.pinValue.emit(key);
    }

}
```

### keypad.component.html

```
<ion-button (click)="handleInput('1')">1</ion-button>
```

Getting really tired of seeing this error:

TypeError: _co.pinEvent is not a function. (In '_co.pinEvent($event)', '_co.pinEvent' is undefined)

Can anyone point out what's going wrong?

Comment: This looks like it should work at first glance... maybe change the method declaration in **home.module.ts** from `pinEvent($event)` to just `pinEvent(event)`

Comment: Removing the $ didn't help, unfortunately.  This is so simple, it's either got to be a typo / missing import, or it's an infrastructure bug.